# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, blogger

I am currently trying to edit my website's template to customize the navigation bar how I want it to be. However, I don't know much about coding and I have altered some things based on the patterns I could see within the coding. Now, when I try to save the changes I've made to the template on Blogger, I get this message:

**Error parsing XML, line 4809, column 21: The element type "ul" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".**

Here is the  part of the coding I am working on:

```
          <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='/p/whatsnew.html'>What's New</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Products</a>
            <ul class='sub-menu'>
              <li><a href='/search/label/Shooter'>Lips</a></li>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                  <li><a href='#'>Satin</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Matte</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Gloss</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Face</a>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                  <li><a href='#'>Foundation</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Highlight</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Contour</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Bronzer</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Blush</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Brows</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Lashes</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Powergame</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Fashion</a></li>
            </ul>
              </li>
```

Maybe someone can help? If so that would be just amazing!

Comment: https://www.onlinewebcheck.com

Comment: I've rolled back the question. If you get an answer, fix the problem you were asking about, and then get a **new** problem: Then ask a new question. Don't edit your question so the existing answers make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <ul class='sub-menu'>
>   <li><a href='/search/label/Shooter'>Lips</a></li>
>   <ul class='sub-menu'>
> ```

Only a `li` can be a child node of a `ul`. You have a `ul` trying to be a child node of another `ul`, which is forbidden.

Comment: To further elaborate, you can have the sub menus inside the li tag.

Comment: bootstrap does that. and the error seems not to be connected to UL or LI.

Comment: @AllDani.com — The question was edited in such a way that it fixed the problem it was asking about (which this is the answer to) and instead asked a very different question.

Comment: Got it. [4moretogo :) ]